# Get dynamic column names from another table for SQL Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table like below:

[image: MTHPERIOD]

And a main table with the below columns:

```
ACC_NO, MTH1, MTH2, MTH3, MTH4, MTH5, MTH6, MTH7, MTH8, MTH9, MTH10, MTH11, MTH12, SELECTED
```

I would like to update the main table for only the column names exists in the temp table. In this case, my desired output would be:

```
Update table_name
Set MTH2 = some_value,
    MTH4 = some_value,
    MTH5 = some_value,
    MTH6 = some_value,
    MTH7 = some_value
Where selected = 'Y'
```

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as the "first" row.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to get this?

Comment: Get "what"? Like Gordon mention, there is no such thing as a "first row" unless you have a specific way to order your data.

Comment: please share sample value and your desired output.

Comment: I have updated my question. @KaziMohammadAliNur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the revised question, you can use `case` expressions:

```
Update table_name
    Set MTH2 = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp tt WHERE tt.monthperiod = 'MTH2') THEN some_value ELSE mth2 END),
        MTH4 = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp tt WHERE tt.monthperiod = 'MTH4') THEN some_value ELSE mth4 END),
        . . .
Where selected = 'Y'
```